# I need a good NoCode responsive HTML builder for Linux

Tags: web-development, wysiwyg

I need a very good nocode website builder.

I want the website to be responsive, so the following are needed features.

1. Can make responsive websites without me having to fiddle with flex and flex direction and align and justify-content and align-content and so on
2. Wysiwyg
3. Simple logic to describe element positions (such as element1.top should be at 30% of screen height - I know that can be done by CSS - but I am looking for a system where I can may be set such logics in a form designer, which will spit out the CSS)
4. Open Source, and free (as in beer and speech)

I tried nicepage on windows via virtualbox. (Wine did not work, crossover did not work) - but it's very clumsy.

I know it might sound odd, but I want it to act as a parametric cad modeller, but for web pages. It should run on Arch or derivatives.

Any ideas are welcome, Thank you